# Launching another java application fails from java web start

Tags: java, executable-jar, java-web-start, runtime.exec

As, it is easy to download jars and other artifacts using
http://code.google.com/p/jnlpdownloader/

So, I am trying to execute my business application from a small launcher application(this launcher application is running as Java web start application).

This launcher application,

- first download executable business application jar from URL(available at runtime only)
- And then execute the executable business jar.

But, the following code doesn't seems to work, nor, it is throwing any exceptions

```
String[] command = {"java -jar", "JarFromURL.jar"};
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            r.exec(command);
        } catch (IOException e1) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voilla...") ;
        }
```

Comment: 1) `exec` throws 3 other exceptions besides `IOException`, what are you doing with those?  2) Be sure to read & implement ***all*** the recommendation of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  By the looks of it, you copied that code from the back of a box of coco-pops. 3) Use `ProcessBuilder` in this millennium.

Answer (score 1):

The array of parameters passed to exec() should be split this way.

```
String[] command = {"java", "-jar", "JarFromURL.jar"};
```

Comment: Also consider `ProcessBuilder`.